# Ember V1.0.0-pre.2: capitalization in handlebars templates

Tags: ember.js

We are using Ember V1.0.0-pre.2 and our handlebars is as follows:

```
{{#each data.Product}}
<div>
  {{Details.uid}} - {{Details.Name}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Our the 'data' bit is from this json:

```
{
    "Product": [
        {
            "Details": {
                "uid": "1",
                "Name": "one"
            }
        },
        {
            "Details": {
                "uid": "2",
                "Name": "two"
            }
        },
        {
            "Details": {
                "uid": "3",
                "Name": "three"
            }
        },
        {
            "Details": {
                "uid": "4",
                "Name": "four"
            }
        },
        {
            "Details": {
                "uid": "5",
                "Name": "five"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This fails with the following warning:

```
WARNING: Watching an undefined global, Ember expects watched globals to be setup by the time the run loop is flushed, check for typos
```

When I change `Details.whatever` to `details.whatever` the warning disappears.

Is this by design or can we get around it somehow? The data is returned from the server in a fixed format and we wouldn't want to use another interim model if we can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Ember has a naming policy where "instances/attributes" always start with a lowercase letter whilst "classes" always start with an uppercase letter. I think that's probably where you are running into some issues, if possible you should be de-serialising your JSON into attributes starting with lowercase letters.

Relevant part pulled from the guides (http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/):

> By convention, properties or variables that hold classes are capitalized, while instances are not. So, for example, the variable Person would contain a class, while person would contain an instance (usually of the Person class). You should stick to these naming conventions in your Ember applications.

Comment: The Naming Conventions guide only contains info for default inference of Routes/Controllers/Views/Templates. The specific part about the Class/Instance capitalization is under the Object Model area - http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/

Comment: I am actually aware of this :) --- the issue is that this is a model.  A model should reflect data and Ember's naming conventions should not apply.  If it *does* apply to the data then that should be stated somewhere and we should be transforming the data.  I guess one cannot always control what is returned from a back-end and performing extra work because the framework is interfering with data is somewhat of a hassle.  So I guess the question is simply: do the naming conventions apply to model data?

Answer (score 0):

Naming convention apply also to model data, but if you can't change what is coming from your API you can get around this by defining a map on a per property basis, e.g.

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Product', {
  details: {key: 'Details'},
  name: {key: 'Name'},
  fooBar: {key: 'FOO_BaR'}
  ...
});
```

see here for more reference on how to map your json to your models: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/mixins/mappable.js

hope it helps

Comment: In our case we are not using Ember Data.  We are providing a plain js object as the data.  So if it applies I guess we are left using an interim model :(

Comment: with no ember data I'm afraid that there is no mapping mixin... :(

Comment: have you thought updating the ember versions? is there too much to rewrite in your case? I guess you would go far better having an actual version of ember in use

Comment: We are working towards version 1 and have started looking at the work involved on RC3.  Things is our framework is built on pre2 currently and we have a team of probably around 150 folks working on a massive rewrite that has some serious deadlines and it is non-trivial.  The other scrum teams want to limit any fixes as is so the upgrade is going to be a project in itself and some serious sprints :(